# How to get cpu, memory used by a process launched via the Java process API?

Tags: java, linux, memory, process, cpu

Hi I need to start a Linux process from the Java API (ProcessBuilder.start()). Is there some way I can monitor this child process for memory, cpu usage etc? I will be starting more than one process at any one time.